# Why do we use synchronized collection if it doesn't guarantee the synchronized access on iterators?

Tags: java, iterator, java.util.concurrent, synchronizedcollection

For example, in the code below, we have to wrap list in a synchronized block when doing the iteration. Does the Collections.synchronizedList make the list synchronized? Why do we do this if it doesn't provide any convenience? Thanks!

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,3,52)));

synchronized(list) { 
      for(int data: list)
         System.out.print(data+" "); 
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Stack Overflow has built-in syntax highlighting. It's better for search engines, for accessibility, for people using mobile data, for us to copy and paste into our IDEs, etc etc etc. Paste the relevant parts of your code into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html

> The reason is that iteration is accomplished via multiple calls into the collection, which must be composed into a single atomic operation.

Also see https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized-collections

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we do this if it doesn't provide any convenience

That it does not help you when iterating is not the same as providing no convenience.

All of the methods - `get`, `size`, `set`, `isEmpty` etc - are synchronized. This means that they have visibility of all writes made in any thread.

Without the synchronization, there is no guarantee that updates made in one thread are visible to any other threads, so one thread might see a size of 5 which another sees a size of 6, for example.

The mechanism for making the list synchronized is to make all of its methods `synchronized`: this effectively means that the body of the method is wrapped in a `synchronized (this) { ... }` block.

This is still true of the `iterator()` method: that too is `synchronized`. But the `synchronized` block finishes when `iterator()` returns, not when you finish iterating. It's a fundamental limitation of the way the language is designed.

So you have to help the language by adding the synchronized block yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper is used to synchronize addition and removal elements from wrapped collection.

JavaDoc mentions that iteration is not synchronized an you need to synchronize it yourself.

```
 * It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
 * list when iterating over it
```

But other access operations are thread-safe and also establish **happens before** relation (since they use `synchronized`).

Comment: Thanks, but I think iterator use "multiple calls" simply explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedList` method synchronises methods like `add`, `remove`. However, it does not synzhronize `iterator()` method. Consider the following scenario:

- Thread 1 is iterating through the list
- Thread 2 is adding an element into it

In this case, you will get `ConcurrentModificationException` and hence, it's imperative to synzhronize the calls to `iterator()` method.